# Angular (7/8/9) and ngx-translate - not translating on direct routing path access

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular8, ngx-translate

I have a quite simple Angular app (currently in version 8), where I have routing, and recently I've added the ngx-translate package, in order to be able to present all the text in more than one language (according to a pre-selected language).
Basically, I got the hang of working with ngx-translate and it's quite simple, but now when I go to the site directly to a certain path, i.e mysite.com/users, the content of the main component is not translated and shows the original translation object name, i.e "general.titles.users".
In such a case, when I navigate to a different path, and then navigate back to this path in the example (via a link with routerLink), the content of the main component is translated fine.
I don't understand what is missing exactly, so that on initial direct access to a certain path (like in the example here) will initiate the translation service (or whatever it is) to work correctly.
The ngx-translate "loader" is defined within a shared module that is available for all the components in the app, and the initialization of this translation service is defined within a component that is always initialized and working (in this case, it's the header component, which always exists and working in the app).

This is a link to GitHub, where I've put all the project's files:

https://github.com/kobibentata/wonday-public

(of course, this requires running "npm install" or "yarn" before running the project locally)

When you run it, access one of the routes directly in the URL.
For example:

http://localhost:4200/events

You'll notice that the title of the main content component is not translated immediately (instead of the translated title text, it reads "sidebar.events", which is from the language json object for ngx-translate).
But if you switch to another page from the sidebar, and then go back to the "Events" page, now the title is translated like it should.

So, what I fail to understand is why this translation does not work on direct access to a route page, but only after being already in the app...

I'm probably missing something simple in definitions or something like that.

Comment: put it on stackblitz. Nonetheless putting things on github will also help for the time being to look into the issue.

Comment: Share the code that doesn't work. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How can I upload an entire angular project (~900KB, without the node_modules folder) into an existing project on StackBlitz?... Right now, I see only the option to create the files manually, and there are quite a few of them...